# Memory Out of Exception while loading data into a datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, datatable

I am trying to get data from a stored procedure and trying to load those data into a datatable using the Load method. Below is my code

```
     using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            DataTable addDataTable;
            using (SqlCommand orgCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetTable", sqlConnection))
            {
                orgCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                orgCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
                sqlConnection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = orgCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    addDataTable = new DataTable();
                    addDataTable.TableName = "TableName";
                    addDataTable.Load(reader);
                    dataSet.Tables.Add(addDataTable);
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = addDataTable;
```

This stored proc returns lot of rows and while trying to load in a data table, the code 'addDataTable.Load(reader)' throws the below memory out of exception. Is there any other alternative or any optimizing techniques to load this huge amount of data into a datatable?

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
HResult=-2147024882
Message=Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
StackTrace:
   at System.Data.RBTree`1.TreePage..ctor(Int32 size)
   at System.Data.RBTree`1.AllocPage(Int32 size)
   at System.Data.RBTree`1.GetNewNode(K key)
   at System.Data.Index.InitRecords(IFilter filter)
   at System.Data.Index..ctor(DataTable table, IndexField[] indexFields, Comparison`1 comparison, DataViewRowState recordStates, IFilter rowFilter)
   at System.Data.DataTable.GetIndex(IndexField[] indexDesc, DataViewRowState recordStates, IFilter rowFilter)
   at System.Data.DataColumn.get_SortIndex()
   at System.Data.DataColumn.IsNotAllowDBNullViolated()
   at System.Data.DataTable.EnableConstraints()
   at System.Data.DataTable.set_EnforceConstraints(Boolean value)
   at System.Data.DataTable.EndLoadData()
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at System.Data.Common.LoadAdapter.FillFromReader(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader, LoadOption loadOption, FillErrorEventHandler errorHandler)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader)
   at WindowsFormsApplication4.Form1..ctor() in C:\Users\Anish George\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4\WindowsFormsApplication4\Form1.cs:line 35
   at WindowsFormsApplication4.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Anish George\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4\WindowsFormsApplication4\Program.cs:line 19
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Anish

Comment: Why try to load so much data at once? Displaying it would be near impossible. Why not implement paging of some sort?

Comment: I agree with @BarryO'Kane, you might want to add paging/pagination, working with TOP and OFFSET or simmilar

Comment: Actually, in real time use, we are not showcasing all the values. We are just getting the values from different stored procedures and storing it into a dataset and finally, we are just showcasing the filtered values from that dataset. This kind of method is almost working in all the scenarios but it is failing only in some of the machines due to performance issue of that particular machine I believe. Is there a way to optimize without changing the architecture?

Comment: Allthough paging will make the form load again, it will throw the same exception when the users keep pushing the page down button... When there is too much data to hold then its a good idea to not allow opening without setting a filter first

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already by @SlapY and @Barry O'Kane you should probably implement some kind of paging and/or lazy loading of new data as the user requires more and more.
Do not try to load everything at once when you deal with lists of items, instead load groups of X items, where X is a count that makes sense for your use case.

When working with Lists of items always have in mind that in most cases these lists have the potential to be huge.
By potential i mean that most of the time there is no hard-limit on lists of things you are trying to represent... (i.e count of users, count of logins made etc)

For example if you were creating a data-table/data-grid for your app's users, you would have to load users by pages, X at a time ( maybe 10, maybe 50, maybe the user can decide between some range of page sizes).
If you had no pages and instead wanted to lazy load as the user scrolls down, you would again have to bring in new data in rows of X items, in order to maintain performance and scalability